# What is the difference between calling addEventListener() vs. adding the event + function into the HTML tag

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between using addEventListener() in your Javascript code like this example:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.element')).forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('ondrop', drop);
});
```

And calling the function directly in a HTML Tag?

```
<div class="element" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
<div class="element" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
<div class="element" ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is one aside from the obvious syntax, and timings around when the event is actually added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `addEventListener` can add multiple events, whereas with `onclick` this cannot be done.
2. `onclick` can be added as an HTML attribute, whereas an addEventListener can only be added within `<script>` elements.
3. `addEventListener` can take a third argument that can stop the event propagation.

Both can be used to handle events. However, `addEventListener` should be the preferred choice since it can do everything `onclick` does and more. Don't use inline `onclick` as HTML attributes as this mixes up the javascript and the HTML which is a bad practice. It makes the code less maintainable.

Comment: This isn't specific to onclick, but thanks!

Comment: Nowhere does this question mention onclick, but your points are still valid.

Comment: I told `onclick` for in general